# MVC Form: Post Propertylist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subclass, form-submit

I have a viewmodel which has a List Property of type class X. When I try to post this property to the server, the recived list is always null.

The data transmitted from the client looks like this:

```
...
XXX.[0].Test:false
XXX.[0].Test1:true
XXX.[1].Test:false
XXX.[1].Test1:false
...
```

The ViewModels looks like this:

```
    class ViewModel
    {
       public ViewModel()
       {
          this.XXX = new List<TestViewModel>()
       }
       public List<TestViewModel> XXX { get; set; }
    }

public TestViewModel {
  public bool Test{ get; set; }
  public bool Test1 { get; set; }
}
```

The View is generated with an Edittemplate

Form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ViewModel)
}
```

EditorTemplates:

```
@model List<TestViewModel>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => Model[i].Test)
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => Model[i].Test1)
}
```

The prooblem seems to be the additional Point...( XXX**.**[0] )
Thanks

Comment: Show how you create the view (note the names would need to be `XXX[1].Test1`)

Comment: Added how the view is created....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `EditorTemplate` so the model is the object (not a collection)

TestViewModel.cshtml

```
@model TestViewModel
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Test)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Test1)
```

and the main view to

```
@model ViewModel
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.XXX)
  ....
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method will correctly name the controls with indexers, which will look like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="XXX[0].Test" .../>
<input type="hidden" name="XXX[0].Test" .../>
....
<input type="checkbox" name="XXX[1].Test" .../>
<input type="hidden" name="XXX[1].Test" .../>
```